# Extracting the data minus day using LEAD function

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have the table `PRODUCTINFO` with 2 columns: `PRODUCTID (NUMBER)`, `ALLOWFROM (DATE)` and now I need to insert one more column `ALLOWTO (DATE)`, which is equal `ALLOWFROM` in the next row minus 1 day. If there is no next `ALLOWFROM` for the `PRODUCTID`, `'01-01-1900'` is should be printed.

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTINFO (
    PRODUCTID NUMBER (8,0)
    ALLOWFROM DATE    
);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTINFO
 (PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM)
VALUES (1, '05.01.2018')

INSERT INTO PRODUCTINFO
 (PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM)
VALUES (1, '06.05.2018')

INSERT INTO PRODUCTINFO
 (PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM)
VALUES (1, '06.10.2018')

INSERT INTO PRODUCTINFO
 (PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM)
VALUES (1, '06.20.2018')

INSERT INTO PRODUCTINFO
 (PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM)
VALUES (2, '05.01.2018')

INSERT INTO PRODUCTINFO
 (PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM)
VALUES (2, '06.18.2018')

INSERT INTO PRODUCTINFO
 (PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM)
VALUES (3, '05.01.2018')

INSERT INTO PRODUCTINFO
 (PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM)
VALUES (3, '06.08.2018')
```

I try doing this script, but no result:

```
SELECT PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM,
    LEAD(ALLOWTO, 3,'01-01-1900') OVER (ORDER BY ALLOWFROM) - 1 AS ALLOWTO
    FROM PRODUCTINFO
    ORDER BY PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM;
```

[image: table]

Where am I wrong? How to reach the result?

Comment: is this oracle or mysql ? Those are 2 different database technologies. Please adjust your tags.

Comment: LEAD/LAG are analytical functions that allow you to access the previous/next row of your query. From your explanation you don't need the previous row, but just the previous date value. Try NVL(ALLOWTO,TO_DATE('02-JAN-1900','DD-MON-YYYY') - 1 instead.

Comment: I've removed all the conflicting tags. MySQL and Oracle are completely different RDBMS, and neither use T-SQL (which is used by SQL Server). Please retag only what you are actually using.

Comment: Hi @KoenLostrie! As I explained, I need the new column (third in the table) ALLOW_TO, which is equal the next ALLOWFROM (second column) minus one day. That's why I use LEAD to access the next ALLOWFROM row.

Comment: Hi @Larnu! It's done - I'm using PL/SQL

Comment: @hatorihanso. Please provide proper reproducible example: create table script, insert sample rows. That makes it easier for us to understand the actual issue. Images look great, but I can't copy them into sqldeveloper to run...
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @KoenLostrie sorry for that. Added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ?
I ordered by product id (this was not in your question but seems obvious). Suggest you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions098.htm#SQLRF00656) on LEAD/LAG to familiarize yourself with the arguments.

```
SELECT productid,
       allowfrom,
       LEAD(allowfrom - 1,1, TO_DATE('01.01.1900', 'MM.DD.YYYY')) 
         OVER(PARTITION BY productid ORDER BY allowfrom ASC) AS allowto
  FROM productinfo;

 PRODUCTID ALLOWFROM  ALLOWTO   
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 05.01.2018 06.04.2018
         1 06.05.2018 06.09.2018
         1 06.10.2018 06.19.2018
         1 06.20.2018 01.01.1900
         2 05.01.2018 06.17.2018
         2 06.18.2018 01.01.1900
         3 05.01.2018 06.07.2018
         3 06.08.2018 01.01.1900
```

Comment: Not at all. I try to print '01-01-1900' in case when there is no next row for a certain PRODUCTID. For example, I see that after row #4, PRODUCTID 2 goes. So, in this case I should print '01-01-1900', because there is no next ALLOWFROM for the PRODUCTID 1.

Comment: In that case you need to partition by productid. As I said... you should read the docs, not me ;). I updated the answer

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thanks a lot for the answer and the documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAG()` analytic function as in the following query :

```
SELECT PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM, 
       LEAD(ALLOWFROM - 1,1,date'1900-01-01') 
       OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCTID ORDER BY PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM) AS ALLOWTO
  FROM PRODUCTINFO
 ORDER BY PRODUCTID, ALLOWFROM;
```

in which the date literal is properly formatted as the third argument, and the value 1 in the second argument is the offset.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4685d4d7dbf63fa6f9bcc0edae81a233)</kbd>

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. LAG is for the access to the previous row, but I need the next. That's why I use LEAD function.

Comment: you're welcome @hatorihanso , but you told : *in the next row minus 1 day*, I also used `LEAD()` in the previous edit but if this helps you, I can revert.